# jwplayer 8 with pre-roll video and xml file

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html5-video, jwplayer

I try to configure the JW Player 8, make video + ads (pre-rolls). I also have key for JW Player which includes support for viewing advertising (pre-rolls) in the video. Please, help me to create video + ads(pre-roll) in JW Player 8?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.x-art.com/members/player/v8/jwplayer.js?v=86"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="Rj7tDuYSCqZdNKNAqsjWoMDBdHhp1THggDFOUhr0Zj8=";</script>
                            <div id="ekcdnplayer"></div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">

    var playerInstance = jwplayer("ekcdnplayer");

        playerInstance.setup({

        id:'ekcdnplayer',
        sources: <?php echo $x; ?>,
        aspectratio: "16:9",
                                    startparam: "start",
                                    primary: "html5",
                                    preload: "auto",
                                    image: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-G4MV85oRMc8/Wxq6x5dl3DI/AAAAAAAAEPE/d7YLJ3VY_Sc-Z3pp5KTtZdafUP_G4186QCLcBGAs/s1600/wait.jpg",
                                    captions: {
                                        color: "#f3f368",
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        backgroundOpacity: 0,
                                        fontfamily: "Helvetica",
                                        edgeStyle: "raised"
                                    },
                                    logo : {
                                    file: "",
                                    link: "",
                                    over: '1',
                                    out: '1',
                                    timeout: '7',
                                    position:'top-left',
                                    width: '60',
                                    margin: '10',
                                    hide: true,
                                    },
                                    tracks: [{ 
                                        file: '/api/getsub.php?linksub=<?php echo $suben; ?>',
                                        label: "English",
                                        kind: "captions",
                                        "default": true 
                                    }],
                                    captions: {
                                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    backgroundOpacity: 20
                                    },
            advertising: {
            client:"vast",
            admessage:"This is an ad pod. This ad ends in xx seconds.",
            schedule:{
                adbreak1: {
                    offset:'pre',
                    skipoffset: "5",
                    tag: '/api/vast1.xml'
                },

                adbreak2: {
                    offset:'1',                   
                    tag: ''
                },

            }
        }
    });
```